# How to adjust images size with respect to mobile size while using "CarouselSlider" and put button text on that image in flutter?

Tags: android, image, flutter, dart, carousel

I'm trying to create intro walkthrough slider for my app but I am unable to do things right. Using **carousel_slider** provided by pub.dev. I am not able to fill image to entire mobile screen. It leave some empty space on both left and right side.

Using **Carousel Pro** I can't place button or text on the sliding images. I spend hours on some a small issue but wasn't able to achieve what I want.

Here is the code

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(), // Making initializing home sceen
  ));
}

List<String> imgList = [
  "lib/assets/images/sunset.jpg",
  "lib/assets/images/sample3.jpg",
  "lib/assets/images/sample2.jpg",
  "lib/assets/images/sunshine.jpg",
  "lib/assets/images/leaf.png",


];
int current = 0;

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // var _userName = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Container(
              child: ImageCarousel(),
            );
}


class ImageCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageCarouselState createState() => _ImageCarouselState();
}

class _ImageCarouselState extends State<ImageCarousel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

// >>>>>>>>>>>>  C A R O U S E L    S L I D E R    C O D E

    return CarouselSlider(
      height: double.infinity,
      initialPage: 0,
      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        setState(() {
          current = index;
        });
      },
      items: imgList.map((imgUrl) {
        return Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              width: double.infinity,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage(
                  imgUrl,
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Below are the screen shots for more clarification

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXEqL.png) 
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3gQs.png)

Using **Carousel_Pro** provided by pub.dev,  how can I put text or buttons over image.

```
class ImageCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageCarouselState createState() => _ImageCarouselState();
}

class _ImageCarouselState extends State<ImageCarousel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Carousel(
          images: [
          AssetImage("lib/assets/images/sample2.jpg"),
          AssetImage("lib/assets/images/sample3.jpg"),
        ]
    );
```

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMPIm.png)
[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4OcH.png)

Btw I have install all packages and images in pubspec.yaml.

Comment: If you get rid of the `margin` in the `Container`, does that get rid of the white space on the sides?

Comment: Thanks for reply @BenjaminS. No, Margin don't get rid of white spaces. I put it there intentionally for clarification purpose. I will remove it once I solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **carousel_slider** to fill whole page set: `viewportFraction: 1.0`

To put stuff on top of the image create stack:

```
CarouselSlider(
          height: double.infinity,
          viewportFraction: 1.0,
          initialPage: 0,
          enableInfiniteScroll: false,
          items: imgList.map((imgUrl) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    imgUrl,
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Text("TEST")
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        ))
```